# how to add button to reduce and to increase the spped of interval in action script 2.0

Tags: actionscript-2

I have a code with which i can fetch image through internet ... I have completed it. I have to add to button , one to increase and one to reduce the interval ... in action script 2.0

```
import mx.transitions.*;
import mx.transitions.easing.*;
my_pb.mode = "manual";
this.createEmptyMovieClip("img_mc", 999);
var my_mcl:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
var mclListenerbject = new Object();
mclListener.onLoadStart = function(target_mc:MovieClip) {
    my_pb.label = "loading: "+target_mc._name;
};
mclListener.onLoadProgress = function(target_mc:MovieClip, numBytesLoaded:Number, numBytesTotal:Number) {
    var pctLoaded:Number = Math.ceil(100*(numBytesLoaded/numBytesTotal));
    my_pb.setProgress(numBytesLoaded, numBytesTotal);
};
var number:Number = 2000;
var myInterval = setInterval(testInterval, number); //
function testInterval() {
 my_mcl.addListener(mclListener);
 my_mcl.loadClip("http://google.com/l5", img_mc);
}
```

i can create 2 button  but there are some error...

Comment: What kind of error ? and wait, why are you still using AS2.0 ?

Comment: i am new to it... so i start with 2.0

Comment: No. Please don't. AS2.0 is already discontinued many years ago, and AS3.0 is not a direct upgrade of AS2.0 (e.g. syntax is very different).

Comment: oh.. But i have already written ... this... .. and  have u any idea about this

Comment: var number:Number = 2000;
var myInterval = setInterval(testInterval, number);                                                                                                               i think in this       2 on mouse clickevent , ... then number + 1000 or  number- 1000

Comment: i want a button event

Answer (score 2):

If you want change the interval of the `setInterval` function, you have to clear it and then use the function with the new interval value, like this :

```
var delay:Number = 2000;

var interval = setInterval(on_repeat, delay);
function on_repeat() {
    // instructions
}

fast.onPress = function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(on_repeat, delay - 1000);
}
slow.onPress = function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(on_repeat, delay + 1000);
}
```

But, as @Raptor has said, I recommend you to use [ActionScript 3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/first_as3_application.html) instead of the old ActionScript 2.

For example, the code above can simply be replaced by a [Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) object like this :

```
var delay:int = 2000;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(delay);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:TimerEvent):void {
        // instructions     
    })
    timer.start();

fast.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    timer.delay = delay - 1000;
})

slow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    timer.delay = delay + 1000;
})
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: @TOM Nothing, because in the parent timeline, you do : `btn.onPress = function(){ /* instructions */ }` which is equivalent to : on(press) = function(){ /* instructions */ }` as the button action.

Comment: @TOM I don't know exactly how did you include your buttons, but in my example code, I named buttons : fast and slow, so take that in consideration.

Comment: @TOM Verify your code, there is a `+` for the slow button and a `-` for the fast one.

Comment: @TOM We will do easy, could you attach your fla, I'll take a look on it ?

Comment: i did it in action script 3.0 .. it shows successfully.but in pratical case.. the delay is matching

Answer (score 1):

```
 var current_loader:Number = 1;        
 var current_img:Number = 0;            
 this.createEmptyMovieClip('img_01', 999);               
 this.createEmptyMovieClip('img_02', 998);             
 img_01._x = img_01._y=img_02._x=img_02._y=20;            
  var loader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();   

  var listener:Object = new Object();                  
  listener.onLoadStart = function(target_mc:MovieClip) {
 };

 listener.onLoadProgress = function(target_mc:MovieClip,      numBytesLoaded:Number, numBytesTotal:Number) {  
 }; 


  listener.onLoadComplete = function(target_mc:MovieClip) {       
   if (target_mc._name == 'img_01') {             
    img_02._visible = false;               
    } else {                
    img_01._visible = false;            
    }                
};  


 var delay:Number = 2000;                 
 var interval = setInterval(load_image, delay);          
function load_image() {
loader.addListener(listener);               
loader.loadClip("http://google.com/latimage.php?",        _root['img_0'+current_loader]);                                    
current_loader = current_loader == 1 ? 2 : 1;                                        
current_img = current_img == images.length-1 ? 0 : current_img+1;
}                 
  slow.onRelease = function() {               
  interval = setInterval(load_image, delay+1000);              
  trace(interval);               

 };               
  fast.onRelease = function() {                  
  clearInterval(interval);                
  interval = setInterval(load_image, delay-1000);
  trace(interval);               

 };              
 image_load();
```